# Dispatcher not registering callbacks in jest unit tests

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests for a store in a react+flux app.  I followed the example of setting up the mock dispatcher [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/09/24/testing-flux-applications.html), and my unit test looks like this:

```
jest.dontMock "../../app/scripts/stores/item_store.coffee"
jest.dontMock "object-assign"

describe 'ItemStore', ->
  ShopConstants = require "../../app/scripts/constants/shop_constants.coffee"
  ShopDispatcher = undefined
  ItemStore = undefined
  callback = undefined

  actionBuildQueryString =
    source: "VIEW_ACTION"
    action:
      type: ShopConstants.ActionTypes.BUILD_QUERY_STRING
      size: "4"

  actionReceiveFilterRespData =
    source: "SERVER_ACTION"
    action:
      type: ShopConstants.ActionTypes.RECEIVE_FILTER_RESP_DATA
      data: {item: {} }

  beforeEach ->
    ShopConstants = require "../../app/scripts/constants/shop_constants.coffee"
    ShopDispatcher = require "../../app/scripts/dispatchers/shop_dispatcher.coffee"
    ItemStore = require "../../app/scripts/stores/item_store.coffee"
    callback = ShopDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0]

  it "registers a callback with the dispatcher", ->
    expect(ShopDispatcher.register.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
```

In my item_store.coffee file, I register with the dispatcher as so:

```
ShopDispatcher.register (payload) ->
  action = payload.action

  switch action.type

    when ActionTypes.BUILD_QUERY_STRING
      WebApiUtils.fetchItems(payload)

    when ActionTypes.RECEIVE_FILTER_RESP_DATA
      _setItems(action.data)

  ItemStore.emitChange()
```

I expected the mocked Dispatcher to register the callbacks since that happens in the actual item_store file, which I have told jest to not mock.  However, since ShopDispatcher.register is undefined, it's not being registered, but I am not quite sure why.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does expect(ShopDispatcher.register.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) fail?  I'm not super familiar with CoffeeScript syntax, but is your require in the beforeEach correctly overwriting the ShopDispatcher that you declared at the beginning of the describe?  Without the var key word, I'm not sure what is in scope.  Or is register undefined in your store?  If so, we might need to see more of your store code.

Comment: It is overwriting the `ShopDispatcher = undefined` at the beginning as it should. It is the coffeescript equivalent of
`var cat;`
`cat = "cat";`
Anyway, explicitly mocking the dispatcher with 

`jest.mock "../../app/scripts/dispatchers/shop_dispatcher.coffee" ` 
at the top of the file caused the tests to pass.  I believe that requiring ShopDispatcher was requiring the actual ShopDispatcher which does not have the properties Shop.register.mock caused this test to fail. I am going to dig deeper into jest and write more test.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. Instead of using the  `ShopDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0]` try the `ShopDispatcher.dispatch`. the below code working perfectly for me (using type script).

```
beforeEach(function () {   
    dispatcher = require("../../../src/App/Dispatcher");
    localeStore = require("../../../src/stores/localestore");
    localeAction = require("../../../src/actions/Locale/LocaleAction");
}

it("should translate the element with the value in current locale JSON", function () {
   localeChangeAction = new localeAction(true, locale, localeJson);
   dispatcher.dispatch(localeChangeAction);

   var translatedText = localeStore.instance.TranslateText("login.login-header");
        expect(translatedText).toEqual("Login header");
});
```