# Dispatcher is not registering callbacks in jest unit tests

Tags: reactjs-flux, jestjs

Very similar to [Dispatcher not registering callbacks in jest unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871967/dispatcher-not-registering-callbacks-in-jest-unit-tests)

I have dispatcher.register in real store. In my jest unit tests, mock dispatcher doesn’t have any callbacks registered. Am I missing something here? pls let me know..

```
describe(“Simple store tests",function(){
    var actionTypes = require('../../constants/actionTypes');
    var AppDispatcher, simpleStore, callback;
//mock action
    var getProjects = {actionType: actionTypes.actions.GET_PROJECTS};
//prepare
    AppDispatcher = require('../../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
    simpleStore = require('../simpleStore');
    var simpleActions = require('../../actions/simpleActions');

//callback = AppDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0];       //this one fails

    it('should initialize with no projects in the list',function(){
        var projects = simpleActions.getProjects();
        console.log(AppDispatcher.register.mock.calls.length); *//this comes back as zero*
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you told Jest not to mock your store under test? Also, if you're using `object-assign` in your store you should also tell jest not to mock that too.

Adding these lines at the top of your test - before your first call to describe - will hopefully do the trick:

```
jest.dontMock('../simpleStore');
jest.dontMock('object-assign'); // only if using object-assign

describe('simple store tests', function() {
    // rest of your code as before
});
```